Community discussion on the new ID question close reason
I have some concerns regarding the introduction of this new close reason for ID questions:


Identification questions must contain sufficient detail to meet the site's quality standards. They should be about identifying an actor, movie, TV show, or a specific episode of a TV show and should not consist only of an image. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

I believe that before implementing any new close reasons, it's important to have a thorough community discussion to ensure the wording and criteria are well-defined.
My main concerns with the new ID close reason are:

Since the community has not yet hashed out what constitutes "sufficient detail" or "quality standards" for ID questions, it's premature to include these vague terms in a close reason.

The link in the close reason directs users to the general on-topic content in the Help Center, which does not mention anything about ID questions. It would be more useful to link to our existing ID questions guide: Tips for asking Movie/TV Identification questions.

The new close reason seems very similar to the existing "needs details or clarity" close reason, making it redundant.

The new close reason mentions that ID questions should not consist only of an image, but I haven't seen any such questions on our site since we re-allowed ID questions, suggesting this scenario is not common enough to warrant mentioning in a close reason. Additionally, I don't recall any recent community discussion that proposed adding this text to a close reason.


Given these concerns, I believe it would be better to continue using the existing "needs details or clarity" close reason for ID questions that lack sufficient information, rather than introducing a new close reason without a clear community discussion and consensus. Our sister site, Science Fiction & Fantasy SE, which has much more experience handling ID questions than our site, has no separate close reason for ID questions, suggesting that "needs details or clarity" works fine for ID questions that lack sufficient details.
I believe it would be beneficial for the moderator team to first allow the community to discuss and clarify whether a new close reason specifically for ID questions is desired. If the community deems a new close reason necessary, they should then work to clarify the wording and criteria, ensuring the final result is well-thought-out, before implementation.

+1 to this. Also, when did we decide that ID questions based on images were still off-topic?

So this close reason was the one from before ID questions were banned.  We chose to re-activate this one rather than have nothing because there was much talk recently about having standards for such questions.  It is reasonable to ask what standards the community would want - and having no custom reason is reasonable and I'm not against that.

Would you mind changing the title to refer to the important thing - which is a discussion about the appropriatre close reasons, or standards for ID questions - rather than about the mis-step here.

@iandotkelly I commented before if the moderation team would want to set up a new post, maybe a step-by-step process guide, to show where we were on allowing IDQ's again. This would allow transparency and allow involved community members to help out if needed. Right now we are going to have a new meta post every time something changes or remains unclear it seems...

@iandotkelly I've changed the title accordingly. Please let me know if you have any further feedback.

@iandotkelly - We've already seen this close-reason being used on a perfectly clear ID question. You can dispute the "bad grapes", but you can't dispute that it's ripe for misuse.

@Skooba the problem is that there is not a step by step that we entirely control. The most important barrier is currently the fact that you cannot use the tags on a post, which we cannot change and have made a request for someone on the SE side to do so.  There's nothing objectively wrong with someone like galacticninja or Vaolurum driving the process and moderators using the permissions they have to carry out the community desires. It doesn't need a moderator to lay out a roadmap, they know the site or StackExchange standard practices as well or even better than the moderators.

Honestly given the perception of bias it's probably better that the community drive the process.  They have the enthusiasm to do so and I am happy to pull the required levers.

So we appear to be encountering the usual apathy when it comes to actually discussing policy changes - where the moderation team end up being accused of bias by either doing nothing or making some change based on very little input, especially given one upvote on this is from me.  Ok, I don't have a problem with removing the custom close reason and reflecting what SciFi do.

@iandotkelly - 6 upvotes in a day is hardly 'apathy'. The fact that it's got votes means that others are probably considering answering. I know I certainly was

@iandotkelly I appreciate the removal of the close reason. On the topic of "apathy," it's worth noting that anyone can initiate a meta discussion for a new close reason, allowing the community to weigh in. And I wouldn't say this post had little input; it got 6 upvotes, which is actually more than many main site posts get. Given that meta is less visible, this suggests it received above-average input.

I have deactivated the custom close reason.
The 'lacks detail or clarity' should be what people use to close ID questions based on inadequate detail.
